# How to hide part of a paper but still maintain the cross-references corresponding to this part?

Tags: cross-referencing

suppose I have page 1 and page 2. I want to hide page 1, so that my paper starts from content of page 2. There are some cross reference of theorems in page 1 on page 2, how can I hide page 1, but still make cross reference of theorems in page 1 available? (If I delete page 1, cross references on page 2 will become question marks) Thanks!

Comment: `\include` each section then use `\includeonly` to show the parts to be shown

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! Can you illustrate it with an example?

Comment: well really you were supposed to put a test file in the question:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David Carlisle has already given you the perfect answer. I'll complement it with an example to illustrate.

Now, it is important that you first compile the complete document with all the included files. This is necessary to get the aux files of each included file.

So you either have to include all files during the first compilation pass or comment out the `includeonly`-command altogether:

```
% \includeonly{%
% firstinclude,
% secondinclude,
% thirdinclude,
% }
```

After this is done, you can choose which files to include. For example like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{filecontents*}{firstinclude.tex}
\section{First include}
 \blindtext\footnote{Here be the first footnote.}
 
\blindmathfalse
\blindtext\footnote{Here be the second footnote.}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{secondinclude.tex}
\section{Second include}
Here we have a some really interesting text we wish to reference at some later point\label{super-interesting}
\blindmathpaper\footnote{Here be the third footnote.}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{thirdinclude.tex}
\section{Third include}
Only a couple of pages ago there was some really interesting Text, see page \ref{super-interesting}.\footnote{Here be the fourth footnote.}
\blindenumerate[8]
\end{filecontents*}

\includeonly{%
firstinclude,
% secondinclude,
thirdinclude,
}

\begin{document}

\include{firstinclude}
\include{secondinclude}
\include{thirdinclude}

\end{document}
```

[image: third include]

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful!